# Meteor & Promises?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having a hard time understanding the docs for the Promise package in meteor, does Meteor support promises out of the box on the client side? I havent been able to find an example.

Answer (score 2):

In the current Meteor (1.3) you do not need the Promise package.
Include the [ecmascript](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ecmascript) package instead, this will give you ES6 standard promises and also "await" support, which is much easier to comprehend than just promises, and makes the code more readable.

See for example https://forums.meteor.com/t/start-using-async-await-instead-of-promises-and-callbacks/17037 and https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. Meteor methods has an async callback built into it:

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', foo1, function (err, res) {
  //this code waits for err or res
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used FutureJS:

```
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
  var myFuture = new Future();

  SomeAsynchronousFunction("foo", function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      myFuture.throw(err);
    } else {
      myFuture.return(res);
    }
  });

  return myFuture.wait();
```

So if you're making a `GET` request, replace `SomeAsynchronousFunction()...` with:

```
Meteor.http.call('GET', 'someUrl', function(err, resp) {
  if (err) {
    myFuture.return(err);
  } else {
    myFuture.return(resp);
  }
});
```